# How to combine all records into one row | ORACLE SQL |

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to do it but not able to do it with `list_agg`

I have 1 table which as all table names in it

Table name : `get_tables`

Below are all table names in `get_tables`. get tables as column called `tbl_names`

```
tbl_names
--------------

EMP_1

EMP_2

STUD_1

STUD_2

DEMO_1

STUDENT_DETAILS
```

I have written a consolidated one query to get all tables count

```
select 'SELECT ' ||  '''' || tbl_names || '''' || ' AS TBL , COUNT(*) as CNT FROM  from  tbl_names || 'union'  from get_tables;
```

Basically I am generating below query as an output from above query

```
   0 SELECT 'EMP_1' AS TBL , COUNT(*) from EMP_1 union
   1 SELECT 'EMP_2' AS TBL , COUNT(*) from EMP_2 union
   2 SELECT 'STUD_1' AS TBL , COUNT(*) from STUD_1 union
   3 SELECT 'STUD_2' AS TBL , COUNT(*) from STUD_1 union
   4 SELECT 'DEMO_1' AS TBL , COUNT(*) from DEMO_1 union
   5 SELECT 'STUDENT_DETAILS' AS TBL , COUNT(*) from STUDENT_DETAILS union
```

Now 2 things I want first is above query are records
need to combine all as one query and remove last keyword `union` from last line and replace with `';'`

So that this generated query I can run it in one go from my python script to get all table count with table name

**Expected output :**

```
TABLE         COUNT 
EMP_1           10 
EMP_2           20
STUD_1          40 
STUD_2          50
DEMO_1          50 
STUDENT_DETAILS 100
```

Comment: What happened when you used `listagg`? Share your attempt at any errors

Comment: @AndrewSayer Not able to frame query with `list_agg`

Comment: The name of the function is `LISTAGG`, not `LIST_AGG`.

Comment: @BobJarvis-СлаваУкраїні ... its typo error in my question i tried that LISTAGG

Comment: Are you certain LISTAGG will work (meaning, the result will always be less than 4000 characters)?

Comment: @mathguy : Not sure but will have more table names so the query will be big

Comment: If you are going to use this query from python, it may be more suitable to execute individual `count` query from the python's loop rather than introduce additional contention by accessing too many tables in a single query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way, using LISTAGG to illustrate the method. If you have too many tables, you will need a different way of aggregating (such as XMLAGG), but that's a different issue - you can find hundreds of questions about that here on SO.

Best to use UNION ALL rather than UNION, but if you insist on just UNION, you can modify the solution yourself. Use LISTAGG, but don't include UNION [ALL] in the tokens to be aggregated; rather, use it as the **delimiter**!

For easier reading of the output, I included a newline in the delimiter as well; that's not needed except for debugging. You may choose to remove it after you are satisfied that the query works as expected.

Also, I didn't bother to concatenate a semicolon at the end; you can add that yourself.

**NOTE** - the output is a single row, meaning a single string that contains newline characters (and therefore appears as multiple lines of text). It's NOT spread over multiple **rows**, it's just several lines in a single string in a single row.

**EDIT** Looking at it again, I see that your individual SELECT statements are incorrect (they show the keyword "from" twice, and all SELECT statements are counting the rows in the `get_tables` table instead of in each respective table, and perhaps other mistakes as well). I will let you fix all those mistakes; they are unrelated to the main topic of your question, which was about aggregating the statements - whether correct or otherwise - in the desired way.

**END EDIT** (FURTHER EDIT AT THE BOTTOM OF THE ANSWER)

```
with get_tables (tbl_names) as (
  select 'EMP_1'           from dual union all
  select 'EMP_2'           from dual union all
  select 'STUD_1'          from dual union all
  select 'STUD_2'          from dual union all
  select 'STUD_3'          from dual union all
  select 'STUDENT_DETAILS' from dual
)
-- end of sample data, for testing only; remove WITH clause
-- and use your actual table and column names.
select listagg('SELECT ' ||  '''' || tbl_names || '''' ||
         ' AS TBL , COUNT(*) as CNT FROM  from  tbl_names',
               ' union all' || chr(10))
         within group (order by tbl_names) as sql_str
from get_tables;

SQL_STR                                                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT 'EMP_1' AS TBL , COUNT(*) as CNT FROM  from  tbl_names union all
SELECT 'EMP_2' AS TBL , COUNT(*) as CNT FROM  from  tbl_names union all
SELECT 'STUDENT_DETAILS' AS TBL , COUNT(*) as CNT FROM  from  tbl_names union all
SELECT 'STUD_1' AS TBL , COUNT(*) as CNT FROM  from  tbl_names union all
SELECT 'STUD_2' AS TBL , COUNT(*) as CNT FROM  from  tbl_names union all
SELECT 'STUD_3' AS TBL , COUNT(*) as CNT FROM  from  tbl_names
```

**SECOND EDIT**

The OP's use case requires the generation of a CLOB, so LISTAGG won't work. Here's how the query can be modified to work for CLOB output. I corrected the statement at the same time - see my first EDIT, before the first code block.

To make sure this works correctly, I wrote it for the `ALL_TABLES` view in my schema; the table names are in a column called `TABLE_NAME`. The OP should change these names for his use case.

```
select regexp_replace(
         xmlcast(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, 
           'select ''' || table_name || ''' as tbl, count(*) as cnt from '
           || table_name, ' union all ' || chr(10))) as clob),
       ' union all ' || chr(10) ||'$', ';')
       as sql_string
from   all_tables;
```

**END SECOND EDIT**

Comment: If you are doing counts on tables with many rows you may want to consider adding a parallel hint to help speed these up

Comment: @mathguy Your code work for me but does not work for large number of tables like i have 60 tables its not working ... throwing error : make sure the result is less than the maximum size

Comment: @cafopa2172 - OK, I will add to my answer, showing how to use XMLAGG for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just query the all_tables table (or user_tables or dba_tables) which holds the row count for each table already?

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, NUM_ROWS
FROM ALL_TABLES;
```

Comment: Only partially works few of the tables in different schema so consolidated all as one query to run in that db via scripting

Comment: I prefer this solution, but before that he must gather statistics on tables, so `num_rows` get updated!